# JSON image parsing from localhost

Tags: android, json, parsing, url, listview

I'm working on a project. That could populate list through json. I've parse the data from **http://10.0.2.2/mobile_version/get_supplier_pro_list.php**, and it is displaying me the text but not image, what i've done is

```
// Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        sup_pd_list = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SUPPLIERS);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < sup_pd_list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = sup_pd_list.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String suply_id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String pd_name = c.getString(TAG_PRO_NAME);
            String pd_price = c.getString(TAG_PRO_PRICE);
            String pd_thumbnail = c.getString(TAG_PRO_THUMBNAIL);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_ID, suply_id);
            map.put(TAG_PRO_NAME, pd_name);
            map.put(TAG_PRO_PRICE, pd_price);
            map.put(TAG_PRO_THUMBNAIL, pd_thumbnail);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.single_list_item, new String[] { TAG_PRO_NAME,
                    TAG_PRO_PRICE, TAG_PRO_THUMBNAIL}, new int[] {
                    R.id.pd_name, R.id.pd_price , R.id.pd_thumbnail });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and in logcat, it shows me

```
12-14 03:47:12.743: I/System.out(314): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: fceacd5431438f9d93fb4f885a3b2990.png
12-14 03:47:12.762: I/System.out(314): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: d254d82762217f8e1005013c8926f53e.jpg
```

And through parsing, what i get is

```
{"suppliers":[{"suply_id":null,"pd_name":"car","pd_price":"200000.00","pd_thumbnail":"fceacd5431438f9d93fb4f885a3b2990.png"}],"success":1}
```

Help needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the image on the device or on a remote server (in this case your PHP local site)?

Comment: The image name is in MySQL or the image is stored as bytes in MySQL?  Because your JSON string has what looks like the name of the file `fceacd5431438f9d93fb4f885a3b2990.png` .. If that file is not on the android device, you need to have the full URL to that image

Comment: Yeah. You're right. The image name is stored as varchar in MYSQL and it is displaying the same. But how to get the full URL of the image?

Comment: Depends on where the actual image is stored.  I've created a web service like this before where I've returned the image name and displayed it in the list, but the actual image itself was physically located on my remote (or local) site.  Where is the physical location of those images? Like where can you view them without your android app?

Comment: Physical location is in the images folder. images/product

Comment: Ahh ok, I'm going to dig up my code and post an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things need to happen in order to display the image.  First, you need to change your HashMap to `HashMap<String, Object>()` to accept a drawable object.

Next, you need to get the drawable object from your string name by doing something like this:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int thumb = r.getIdentifier(pd_thumbnail, "com.mypackage");
map.put(TAG_PRO_THUMBNAIL, thumb);
```

Here is a tutorial that you can use to derive things from minus the string to drawable conversion

http://www.androidpractice.com/2012/01/static-listview-with-images-in-android.html

Finally, I'm not sure if `R.layout.single_list_item` is the right type of list item for this, but I may be mistaken, so please don't quote me on that one.